# q text as data: How to fix Error field larger than field limit

Tags: q

I'm trying to sum a column in a medium sized data file (15M rows), but I get the following error:

```
$> q -Ht 'select sum(value) from datafile.txt'

Error('field larger than field limit (131072)'
```

My search led to links suggesting a change of default field size in python parsing of csv.fieldsize(), however after checking with awk I verified that my file has no large fields.

Comment: Merlin: Kindly provide us sample of Input_file and expected output too so that we could help you in same.

Answer (score 0):

***never forget: cleanse your data before processing***

I found that my data file is full of product names with single and double quotes (single quotes for possessive names, and doubles to represent 'inches'. This causes the python parser to read the delimiter as literal characters within the field.

Do this:

```
sed s:\"::g data.txt > tmp ; sed s:\'::g tmp > data.txt
```

Terrible, terrible single/double quotes in data.